# Pyplot axvspan: Multiple colors in one span (vertically)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to highlight a region on the x-axis using more than one color. I've managed to find a solution by sectioning the region along the x-axis, as shown in this figure:
[image]

However, I'd like a solution where the sectioning is happening on the y-axis instead. Take 6362 in the plot as an example. Is there any way to create something like a dashed bar where every other dash (or whatever it's called) is purple and red?

**Edit**
Here's the relevant code for highlighting each subsection horizontally

```
# Find exon's index
e_index = sorted(list(all_samples.ensembl_exon_id.unique())).index(exon)

# Total x-axis span incl offsets
xmin = e_index-0.25  # Start of x-span
xmax = e_index+0.25  # End of x-span
diff = xmax-xmin     # Length of entire span
buf = diff / len(s_names)  # Length of each subsection

# Go through each sample
for sname in s_names:
    # Get color of this sample
    s_color = colors[sname]

    # Get index of this sample
    order = list(s_names).index(sname)

    # Calc xmin and xmax for subsection
    s_xmin = xmin + (buf * order)
    s_xmax = s_xmin + buf

    # Highlight
    plt.axvspan(xmin=s_xmin, xmax=s_xmax, alpha=0.25, color=s_color, zorder=0.6, ymin=0, ymax=1)
```

Comment: You'll have to build that using patches I think: http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/artist_reference.html without seeing your code and data it's difficult to say more.

Comment: @armatita Alright, I'll look into patches, thanks. I added the code for how I'm currently doing the highlighting, if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the `ymin` and `ymax` options to `axvspan` to create each "dash". By looping over the axes interval `0-1`, you can build up all your dashes.

Here's a quick function I put together to make it somewhat automated. Call `vspandash` with your required options to fill the region with dashes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

x=y=np.arange(11)

ax.plot(x,y,'go-')

def vspandash(thisax,xmark,xwidth=0.6,ndash=10,colour1='r',colour2='m'):

    interval = 1./ndash
    hxwidth = xwidth/2.

    for j in np.arange(0,1,interval*2):
        thisax.axvspan(
                xmin=xmark-hxwidth,xmax=xmark+hxwidth,
                ymin=j,ymax=j+interval,
                facecolor=colour1,alpha=0.25,edgecolor='None'
                )
        thisax.axvspan(
                xmin=xmark-hxwidth,xmax=xmark+hxwidth,
                ymin=j+interval,ymax=j+interval*2.,
                facecolor=colour2,alpha=0.25,edgecolor='None'
                )

# Lets explore the different options
vspandash(ax,2)                           # Default width, number of dashes, and colours
vspandash(ax,4,ndash=20)                  # Increase number of dashes
vspandash(ax,6,xwidth=0.3)                # Change width of shaded region
vspandash(ax,8,colour1='b',colour2='g')   # Change colours of dashes

plt.show()
```

[image]